# Classnotfound exception when trying to connect through web.xml

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, jstl

I'm currently doing JSP project using IntelliJ and tomcat 9.0.10, i would like to connect to the database through web.xml so i don't have to define connection in every page. When i do so, i receive this error

```
invalid driver class name: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "
```

i can connect to database just fine if i define the connection in my page (in this case called LoginValidation.jsp), however.

Here's my code in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>driverClass</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>connectionURL</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:xxx/project?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Asia/Pontianak&amp;useSSL=false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>username</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Not sure if this is related, but should i put it inside `<web-app>` instead ?

and here's how i set the connection in LoginValidation.jsp

```
<s:setDataSource var="ds" driver="${initParam['driverClass']}"
                         url="${initParam['connectionURL']}"
                         user="${initParam['username']}"
                         password="${initParam['password']}" />
```

the web.xml in my title refer to WEB-INF/web.xml

Here's where i get this code from [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076526/using-web-xml-to-get-jstl-sql-datasource)

Comment: Do you have mysql.jar present in the artifact libraries? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html

Comment: yes, which is why i can connect to database just fine if i just define the connection in LoginValidation.jsp

Comment: Put your dependencies in $CATALINE_HOME/lib.

Comment: what dependencies?

Comment: @KevinGuswanto All library jar files.

Comment: i can't find $catalina_home at /usr/local i'm using Mac, any idea why ?